# my data renders twice and returns empty on the first

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a project, I am getting multiple objects that all contain specific football match details, so I filter the matches by matchday but I keep getting an empty array on my first render, and then when I leave the tab and come back it then renders the objects I need, how do I get it to render once with my data

Here is my code:

```
//my states
     const [selectedLeague,setSelectedLeague]=useState({})
        const [loading,setLoading]= useState(false)
        const [competitions,setCompetitions]= useState([])
        const [matchday,setMatchDay]=useState([])
        const [matches,setMatches]=useState([])
        const [LeagueName,setSelectedLeagueName]=useState([])
        const area_ids= [2072,2114,2163,2077,2081,2088,2187,2224]
```

so then I'm trying to get matches and filter by matchday

```
const getMatches= async()=>{
  const response = await axios.get(`${FOOTBALL_API_URL}/${selectedLeague}/matches`,{
        method: 'get', 
          headers: { 'X-Auth-Token': `${FOOTBALL_API_TOKEN}`}
  } );
    console.log('checking getmatch response',response)
   const data = await response.data
   console.log('checking response.data',data)

    setLoading(true)
    // set matchday
    setMatchDay(data.matches[0].season.currentMatchday)
    // filter matches by matchday
    const filter = data.matches.filter((match)=>{
     return matchday === match.matchday
  })
    // log the filtered array
    console.log('filtered array',filter)
   
   
  setMatches(filter)
 
 }
```

but I only get the matchday and When filtered list is first rendered it is always an empty list

```
filtered array []length: 0[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

[console log showing empty array on the first render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msONe.png)

I've tried tweaking my use effect but it only loops infinitely

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    getMatches()
}, [matches])
```

but when I leave the page and come back it then gets the data I need

```
filtered array 
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416384, utcDate: '2022-08-05T19:00:00Z', …}
1: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416383, utcDate: '2022-08-06T11:30:00Z', …}
2: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416378, utcDate: '2022-08-06T14:00:00Z', …}
3: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416379, utcDate: '2022-08-06T14:00:00Z', …}
4: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416381, utcDate: '2022-08-06T14:00:00Z', …}
5: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416382, utcDate: '2022-08-06T14:00:00Z', …}
6: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416377, utcDate: '2022-08-06T16:30:00Z', …}
7: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416376, utcDate: '2022-08-07T13:00:00Z', …}
8: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416380, utcDate: '2022-08-07T13:00:00Z', …}
9: {area: {…}, competition: {…}, season: {…}, id: 416375, utcDate: '2022-08-07T15:30:00Z', …}
length: 10
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
```

[console log showing filtered array with requested data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2kKA.png)

I need to get my data on the first render, I am new to hooks, so I'm hoping I'm missing something simple. Thanks.
please if you have any questions please reply to this trend.

Comment: Are you doing the api call when you change the tab also ?

Comment: Is changing tabs the only way you can see your data or it just takes a bit of time before being rendered? Keep in mind `useEffect` will fire once the component has been mounted, so at that first render your state will be an empty array that is going to get populated later.

Comment: yes, I am running another API call when I switch tabs, one table shows the standings of the competitions, and the other shows the matches

Comment: changing tabs is the only way I can see my data (which is wrong) because at first, I have a loader that has to load before the component is rendered, the loading just loads and displays blank information but when I go to the standings tab and come back it then renders the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From react official documentation.

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument. This tells React that your effect doesn’t depend on any values from props or state, so it never needs to re-run.

So, please change your useEffect to next

```
useEffect(() => {
   getMatches();
}, []);
```

And this should solve your problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Lucid,  I've created a video on my channel to explain the problem and how to fix it - https://youtu.be/LLt9LPrOSkw   Please check it out and I hope it helped. Thanks.

Comment: I just watched your video and I really appreciated you illustrating it so clearly, but when I tweaked the useEffect by adding a dependency (matches), i only used it to test and confirm that I get my data only when it runs twice so after testing that theory, I removed the dependency,which means I'm still where I was b4

Comment: if its ok or you have time to spare ,I;d like to better explain it , maybe we can talk more

Comment: @Lucid, I just found the issue with the code. Created another video with the explanations - https://youtu.be/zNoavIlcAXI  Hope this will help. If it does, please upvote the answer, like the video and subscribe to my channel. Thank you.

Comment: Haven't tested it yet ,but i can say without a doubt that you nailed it

Answer (score 0):

```js
//state

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); 
....
///

useEffect(()=>{
  if(matches.length > 0){
    setLoading(false)
    return; // shortcircut in case the data is here first(optional)
    }

  let results = getMatches();
  let filteredMatches = results.filter(()=>{/*filter function*/});
  setMatches(filteredMatches); //seting the state will cause a re-render
  setLoading(false); // this second state change wont cause another re-render cause there is one pending
}, []); // pass in an empty array to say there are no dependencies that effect should watch


return( loading ? {"Fetching the matches"}: <Component/> ); //on the first render, matches will be empty,
```

The second parameter in useEffect determines when and how often that effect runs, it runs when ever the data place there changes, Usually you want your app to fetch the data once then render, then you should pass in an empty array. In addition, your component will likely mount before the request is completed, so u need to handle what it should render while its waiting. React has a concept called Suspense for this case, or you can use or `loading` state like this `return ( loading ? <p>"..loading"</p> : <component/>)`

Comment: i already did that, didnt work

Comment: on certain components, i wrote if loading is true then render the loading component, and loading is only false when then data is available, so you would think that the loading component, in this case, will run infinitely by it doesn't, it loads and then renders the empty array

Comment: you need to set the initial state of isLoading to true, and add a call to setLoading(false) to the bottom of the getMatches function, your core problem is you have a race condition, React is ready to render before the data has arrived, you need to tell react to re-render after the data is there, changing the state (not aways) forces a re-render